# Sometimes I cannot spawn on my teammates on Hardcore

Tags: battlefield-4

The other day I was playing Operation Locker Conquest in Hardcore mode on PS3 and for some reason I could not spawn from SOME of my teammates. I vividly remember spawning on a teammate but not the other two. Is this a Hardcore thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servers can choose to disable spawning on squad mates, and only allow spawning on your squad leader. If you are the squad leader, you cannot spawn at a team mate.

You can use this filter to find servers that use this feature:

[image: Advanced - Only Squad Leader Spawn]

Comment: I think that if you are a squad leader, you CAN spawn on ANY squad member

Comment: @novarg now that you mention it, I'm not sure. Need to check it.